# Is it possible to create GSI on 2billion items in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

Is it possible to create 2 Global Secondary Index in DynamoDB table which has 2Billion items in it.
What would be the time consumed to create these indexes

Answer (score 1):

You can create a GSI on a any size table. You can only create 1 GSI at a time, so you'll need to create the first GSI, wait for it to complete, and then create the second GSI.

The time it will take will depend on the amount of spare WCUs. Example from the docs:

> Determine the number of additional WCUs that you need by dividing the table size in kilobytes by your desired backfill time. For example, suppose that you have a 1 GiB (1,074,000 KB) table. You want the backfilling process to complete in 10 minutes (600 seconds). Here's how many WCUs that you need: 1,074,000 / 600 = 1,790 WCUs

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-gsi-dynamodb/)

If you have 2B docs that are all about 1kib in size, you may need something in the order of 100k-1M WCUs.